Sum over squares.
It is knowed that $$\sum_{d^2 \mid n} \mu(d)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text { if } n \text { is square-free, } \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{array}\right.,$$ hence if we take $\sum^*$ to mean sum over squarefree numbers, we can remove the squarefree condition: $\sum_n^*=\sum_n\sum_{d^2\mid n}\mu(d)$.
I want to know whether we have a similar expression like:$$\sum...=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text { if } n \text { is square, } \\ 0 & \text { otherwise. }\end{array}\right.$$
hence if we meet sum over squares, we can remove the square conditon like above.

A square has an odd number of divisors, so $\sigma_0(n) \pmod 2$ does what you want without a sum (or with the sum hidden in the definition of $\sigma_0$)

What is $\sigma_0(n)$?

The number of divisors of $n$.  It is one of the divisor functions.

thanks, I get it.

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\lambda(d)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $n$ is a square}\\
0&\text{ if $n$ is not a square}\end{cases}$$
where $\lambda$ is the Liouville function.

thank you very much, it is what I wanted.

@cauchyMax If this answer your question you could accept my answer.
